What's the significance of degrevlex over deglex?
I keep reading that degrevlex ordering generally works best with Groebner basis calculations but I'm confused as to why this generally works best. It seems like it's mentioned here, but I can't parse it for the life of me.

The reverse lexicographic order is defined by: $x^A > x^B$ if the FIRST non-zero entry of the vector of integers A-B is NEGATIVE. This is a local order, not a global order.  Therefore Gröbner bases over this ring only give generators over the local ring whose fractions are all elements not in the ideal generated by the variables.

